# Javascript/Parse: Convert returned date format

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Parse with Javascript in order to retrieve data from my database. To get the date I am using the result.createdAt function they recommend.

However, it is returning a date format like: "Wed Apr 02 2015 23:11:27 GMT-0400(Eastern Daylight Time)". Is there an easy javascript/parse date function for me to convert this to a format that doesn't write out the whole date, for example "04/02/2015 23:11".

Comment: you can try stuffing the whole string into `var d = new Date(string_goes_here)` and hope for the best.

Comment: then there's http://www.datejs.com/, which makes date handling in JS much more pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run it into a new Date `new Date("Wed Apr 02 2015 23:11:27 GMT-0400(Eastern Daylight Time)")`

After that, you will only have to use `getMonth getFullYear` etc.